# How can I install application on the new iOS 8 using xCode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, itunes

How can I install application on the new iOS 8 using xCode 5? I've used iTunes for that before. But now it doesn't work. Application's icon is gray on the iTunes.

Comment: You don't install apps via Xcode though do you?  So what do you mean?

Comment: xCode 5 doesn't support the new beta iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps helped me:

1. Add and install Ad-Hoc mobile profile.
2. Create Ad-Hoc .ipa file with Organizer.
3. Add it to the iTunes and sync the device.
4. Remove non-existent application from the device on iTunes and from iTunes **(most important step for me)** and sync the device.
5. Add it again to the iTunes and sync device.

Now you can test your new version of the application on iOS 8!

Comment: don't you need a device to archive for the step 2? so if your device doesn't get recognized by xcode, you are screwed.

Comment: By using this method I guess we cannot debug the same! is there a possibility to add the same to the device using Xcode itself?

Answer (score 1):

more simple:

I got an analogous problem in iOS8 beta era using xCode 5.1

xCode refuses to recognize my iPhone 5, (yellow pin..).
You can fool xCode using a symbolic link (xCode will assume it can handle ios8.. too)

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.1\ (11D167) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0\ (12A4265u)

Comment: It doesn't help: `Could not support development.`

Comment: may be a misspelled cmd, but id DOES work. I reopened my shell and copy/past:

Comment: from my shell (copy/paste)

Comment: I reopen my shell and made copy/ paste:

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.1\ \(11D167\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0\ \(12A4265u\)
PLS verify your path, but is simply a symbolic link.

Comment: iOS 8 device still isn't supported by xCode 5 without xCode 6.